# Where to put bearer authorization token in this curl api

Tags: php, laravel, bearer-token

I am using this new API feature of imageqrcode (https://imageqrcode.com/apidocumentation) to dynamically generate image QR code, using php:

```
$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; //secret

// instantiate data values
$data = array(
    'apikey' => $api_key,
    'qrtype' => 'v1', 
    'color' => '000000',
    'text' => 'https://wikipedia.com',
);

// connect to api
$url = 'https://app.imageqrcode.com/api/create/url';
$ch = curl_init($url);

// Attach image file
$imageFilePath = 'test1.jpg';
$imageFile = new CURLFile($imageFilePath, 'image/jpeg', 'file');
$data['file'] = $imageFile;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Handle the response
$result = json_decode($response, true);

if ($result && isset($result['downloadURL'])) {
    // Successful request
    $download_url = $result['downloadURL'];
    echo "Download URL: $download_url";
} else {
    // Handle errors
    echo "Error: " . print_r($result, true);
}
```

### In the documentation, it shows there is a variable "serialkey":

Image QR Code API Documentation

**API Documentation**

Effective Date: November 15th, 2023

Image QR Code API is a service that accepts an HTTPS request to generate an image or gif qr code, used mostly by developers.

1. Image QR Code - URL

REQUEST IN JSON (POST): https://app.imageqrcode.com/api/create/url

apikey //your apikey
serialkey //your serialkey
qrtype //string, min 2 chars, max 2 chars e.g. v1 or v2, v1 for QR Type 1 & v2 for Type 2
color //numeric, min 6 digit, max 6 digit e.g. 000000 for black
text //url, min 15 chars, max 80 chars e.g. https://yourwebsite.com
file //image file (jpg/jpeg/png), max 1 MB filesize

---

There is no information on where to put this serialkey as a standard bearer authorization token. I can't connect to the API without this information.

I tried to connect it without the bearer token as I thought it could be anonymously connected to the API, but it also doesn't work. I am very confused now as I am still learning PHP and Laravel.